# Рекурсивная функция(cкобочная последовательность)

Tags: python

Решение задачи скобочных последовательностей(не мое). Решил разобраться, как работает, расставил printов.

```
def foo(search, left, right, pairs):
    if left == pairs and right == pairs:
        print(search)
    else:
        print(left, right, 'else',)
        if left < pairs:
            print(left, right,'left')
            foo(search + '(', left + 1, right, pairs)
        if right < left:
            print(left, right, 'right')
            foo(search + ')', left, right + 1, pairs)


foo('', 0, 0, 3)
```

До генерации первой правильной последовательности `((()))`, принты появлялись в ожидаемые местах. После нее уже не все так очевидно. Вот принты от первой до повторной правильных последовательностях:

```
((()))
2 0 right
2 1 else
2 1 left
3 1 else
3 1 right
3 2 else
3 2 right
(()())
```

Вопрос, почему `left, right = 2, 0`, в первом примет после правильной последовательности?

Задача: Требуется вывести все правильные скобочные последовательности длины `2 ⋅ pairs`. В задаче используются только круглые скобки.

Comment: Вы бы хоть рассказали, что за задача, что эта функция должна делать, и что обозначают её аргументы. А то получается, что человек, которые знает смысл кода просит по нему объяснений у людей, которые этого не знают.

Comment: @Xander, Обновил условие.

Comment: Запустил вашу программу. Получается другая последовательность print 0 2 right, 2 1 else и т.д.

Comment: @becouse Поправил код

Answer (score 6, accepted):

После вывода ((())) завершается рекурсивный вызов foo('((()))',3,3,3). 
Она возвращает управление той функции, которая его вызвала и т.д. Функция, которой возвращено управление либо завершается, либо делает рекурсивный вызов.

Смотрите. Сначала полностью заполняем левые скобки, потом к ним ставим правые скобки. У вас два семейства рекурсивных вызовов.

Вот эта часть кода формирует дерево рекурсивных вызовов для постановки левых скобок

```
if left < pairs:
            print(left, right,'left')
            foo(search + '(', left + 1, right, pairs)
```

После того как они все закончатся, идут вызовы для правых скобок

```
if right < left:
            print(left, right, 'right')
            foo(search + ')', left, right + 1, pairs)
```

На рисунке я указал передачу управления красным цветом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Как получен рисунок рекурсивных вызовов.

1. Библиотека [rcviz](https://github.com/carlsborg/rcviz)
2. Требует pygraphviz, которая требует [graphviz](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/). C этой библиотекой есть несколько проблем и установка под Windows довольно замороченная

   ```
   -Установите компилятор MSFT C ++.
   -Установите Anaconda для Win AMD64, Python3 .
   -Установите graphviz для Win .
   -Добавьте C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin в переменную среды PATH.
   -Загрузите pygraphviz-1.3.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl .
   -Создайте среду Conda с Python версии 3.4: conda create --name digraphs python=3.4 anaconda .
   -Войдите в среду: activate digraphs.
   -Установите pygraphviz, используя pip: pip install pygraphviz-1.3.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl.
   -Выполнить пример: python ./get.py.
   -Выйти из среды: deactivate
   ```

Код для построения дерева

```
from rcviz import callgraph, viz

@viz
def foo(search, left, right, pairs):
    if left == pairs and right == pairs:
        print(left, right, 'done', )
        print(search)
    else:
        print(left, right, 'else',)
        if left < pairs:
            print(left, right,'left')
            foo(search + '(', left + 1, right, pairs)
        if right < left:
            print(left, right, 'right')
            foo(search + ')', left, right + 1, pairs)


foo('', 0, 0, 3)
callgraph.render("foo.png")
```

Comment: Спасибище за рисунок

Comment: @becouse Как Вы сделали такой рисунок? :) Не уж то ручками? Или есть какой-то сервис для генерации?

Comment: Ну сейчас на каждый чих есть библиотека.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу про рисунок, скажите пожалуйста название библиотеки. А то в прошлом пробовал пару инструментов для рисования схем, но так и не смог добиться красивого результата как на вашей иллюстрации.

Comment: @Xander Добавил пример в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace Test {
    class Program {

        static void Main() {
            PrinBrackets(Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine()));
        }

        private static void PrinBrackets(short count, string s = "", short left = 0, short right = 0){
            if(left == count && right == count) {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            } else {
                if(left < count) {
                    PrinBrackets(count, s + '(', (short)(left + 1), right);
                }
                if(right < left) {
                    PrinBrackets(count, s + ')', left, (short)(right + 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]